# Google geocode returns location in wrong state

Tags: google-geocoder

I used this geocode url to lookup the lat long for a locality Arlington,OR,US:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&client=gme-skybitzinc&address=Arlington,OR,US&signature=0QfQBztVSVeS4bimxF2zBHluzJU=

and I got a lat long in Arlington TX:
32.7356870,-97.1080656

How can I prevent this?  Is this a known issue?

Several other cities -- all in Oregon -- get results in the wrong state:
Aurora, Harrisburg, Jefferson, Oakland, Toledo, and more.

If I change the capitalization, a lat long in Oregon is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue.

The similar problem was reported in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830289

Hopefully Google will solve it soon. You can star the public issue to receive further updates from Google.

In the meantime, I found the following workarounds

- Remove US from address string https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DArlington%252COR%26nfw%3D1
- Use complete name of the state https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DArlington%252COregon%252CUS%26nfw%3D1
- Use component filtering with a complete state name https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DUS%26in_administrative_area%3DOregon%26in_locality%3DArlington%26nfw%3D1

Hope it helps!

PS. It looks like you have a Premium plan license (client ID). In this case you can file a support case in Cloud support portal:

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support

Comment: Thanks, this is a very informative and helpful answer.  We did open a google support issue; the recommendation was to use the complete state name.